# Disable title in org latex export

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

Is it possible to completely disable the title, i.e. **not even `\title{}`**, when export org file to latex? I am using org mode to write paper the latex template provided by the publisher does not allow `\title{}` command appears before `\begin{document}`

I tried many solutions found online but neither of them works with the latex template I am using. Currently, I put `#+BIND: org-latex-title-command "` in my org file. From the source code in `ox-latex`, I found the following code inside `org-latex-template (contents info)`:

```
     ;; Title and subtitle.
     (let* ((subtitle (plist-get info :subtitle))
        (formatted-subtitle
         (when subtitle
           (format (plist-get info :latex-subtitle-format)
               (org-export-data subtitle info))))
        (separate (plist-get info :latex-subtitle-separate)))
       (concat
    (format "\\title{%s%s}\n" title
        (if separate "" (or formatted-subtitle "")))
    (when (and separate subtitle)
      (concat formatted-subtitle "\n"))))
```

Does this mean that there is no way to get rid of the `\title{}` command in the exported latex file?

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with this little advice function that removes the `\title{...}` line from the output:

```
(defun my-org-latex-remove-title (str)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "^\\\\title{.*}$" "" str))

(advice-add 'org-latex-template :filter-return 'my-org-latex-remove-title)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and it does work well. However, I changed the regexp replace function to `(replace-regexp-in-string "^\\\\title{}$" "" str)` so it only replaces  an empty `\title{}` command, which could be useful if i want to reserve the title in other situations.